# JpGraph Error General PHP error : include(): Failed opening 'src/jpgraph.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Tags: php, path, include, jpgraph

I want to do an include jpgraph.php to a reporte.php.
The path of the report is:

> D:\xampp\htdocs\web2project-master\modules\reports\reports\reporte.php
>   The path of the jpgraph is:
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\web2project-master\modules\lib\jpgraph\src\jpgraph.php

My code is:

```
$file = ((dirname(__FILE__)))."\..\..\..\lib\jpgraph\src\jpgraph.php";
include_once($file);
```

I get this message:

> JpGraph Error General PHP error : include(): Failed opening
>   'src/jpgraph.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR').

I have tried solutions from other questions but I don't know how to adapt them to my directories.
How do I fix this error?
Thanks for all help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your `pgraph.php` in root folder.(check the file structure below)

```
index.php
lib
    jpgraph
        src
            jpgraph.php
```

so `index.php` you have to use

```
$file = './lib/jpgraph/src/jpgraph.php";
include_once($file);
```

> If you use `../` it will go one folder back